# Docker exec pipe No such file or directory

Tags: docker

For some reason `>` is not finding the file test.txt, but `ls` is.

```
$ docker exec mycont ls /headless/Desktop
test.txt
$ docker exec mycont ls /headless/Desktop > /headless/Desktop/test.txt
-bash: /headless/Desktop/test.txt: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
docker exec mycont bash -c "ls /headless/Desktop > /headless/Desktop/test.txt"
```

You want docker to look for the file in the container, not on the host